# Tag Request, Beyond Standard Model

Tags: feature-request, tags

The title sums it well.

While `Beyond Standard Model` is an active area in physics(Check [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all:+AND+model+AND+Beyond+standard/0/1/0/all/0/1), there are more than displayable results), we don't have a tag for it. I basically wanted to use it for [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71967/proton-radius-puzzle), but I couldn't find anything related to it.

Comment: Hm, that would be a very broad tag... We have more specific ones for BSM physics topics like [tag:supersymmetry], etc for example. To make a new tag while tagging, you can just type in the word followed by enter, to create it.

Comment: @Dilaton Thanks for the note.

Comment: (Not quite: [you need 300 rep for that](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).)

Comment: Related tags: [tag:unified-theories] and [tag:grand-unification].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I first did not see much use of a BSM tag too, but no I think it can be useful and we should have one for the following reasons:

- I agree with what Matt Reece said in his comment: there's some effect
  which is not present in the SM and a question about what it means and
  how it can be interpreted, not linked to any particular model.
  General things like questions involving bounds on higher-dimension
  operators---of which the proton charge radius is, more or less, an
  example---would be a good use of this tag
- At the LHC, in addition to very specific searches for BSM physics
  which can clearly be ascribed to a particular theory/concept/model
  such as supersymmetry or string theory, people do more general
  broader searches for BSM physics effects which can not be uniquely
  related to a single known theoretical idea, such as extra
  dimensions, violations of fundamental symmetries, or more generally
  for deviations from the SM one would not yet know how to interpret
  them at present, too. Questions dealing with such issues could not be
  tagged with string-theory, supersymmetry, etc.

Exactly to fill this gap, [bsm](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bsm) is usefull and it would be useful for people who want to ask and/or look for questions which deal with more general BSM phenomenology including more exotic effects, which are not covered by the specific tags denoting BSM theories and concepts we have.

Answer (score 4):

The diversity of possible theories and possible observation that our Beyond the Standard Model (tm) is enormous, and the tag would be so broad that it would provide little characterization of the question. Consider that [it is non-unreasonable to consider neutrino oscillation as "beyond the standard model"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5118/why-are-neutrino-oscillations-considered-to-be-beyond-the-standard-model).

Like Dilaton noted in the comments we are better served by a set of more specific tag.

Comment: I don't agree and think the context of the OP is exactly the right one where this kind of tag is needed: there's some effect which is not present in the SM and a question about what it means and how it can be interpreted, not linked to any particular model. General things like questions involving bounds on higher-dimension operators---of which the proton charge radius is, more or less, an example---would be a good use of this tag.

Comment: As @MattReece pointed, I think I couldn't actually pick a specific branch of Beyond Standard Model, so I really needed the tag.

Comment: What @MattReece seems very reasonable too, maybe we can have such a tag for exactly the purpose he mentions and write in the tag wiki that not every question asking about supersymmetry for example should be tagged with it too? Math Reece could certainly write a nice tag wike ;-)

Comment: And @MattReece maybe you have something reasonable and helpful to say concerning [these](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4567/2751) issues too? I boldly quoted one of your main page comments hoping you do not mind ...